# Can't change brightness on HP Envy x360 13z-ay000 laptop (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, display, brightness, amd-graphics, backlight

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and the brightness controls do not work. When I press the built in brightness control keys, the brightness bar pops up and goes up and down but it doesn't actually do anything. Additionally, the screen is very dim (about half the brightness when I use windows 10).
I have tried:

- Installing brightness-controller. None of the controls affect the brightness in any way.
- Using xrandr. When I type `xrandr`, it outputs the following:

  `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`

  `Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080`

  `default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm`

  `1920x1080     77.00*`

  and when I type `xrandr --output default --brightness 1` it outputs `xrandr: Gamma size is 0.`
- Changing the line in /etc/default/grub to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` This just stops the brightness keys from working altogether. I also tried changing the value of `acpi_backlight` to `none` and that doesn't work either.
- Changing the value of /sys/class/backlight/brightness. The value of that file actually does change when I press the brightness keys but the brightness doesn'tchange. By the way, the value of /sys/class/backlight/max_brightness is 49 and I can't change that, even as root.
- Installing [amd gpu drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635) from the official website. That completely stopped ubuntu from booting until I removed them.
- Installing amd gpu PPA third-party repository drivers. That didn't change anything.

I don't know if this is relevant but the output of `sudo lshw -c video` is:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED
   
 description: VGA compatible controller

 product: Renoir

 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

 physical id: 0

 bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0

 version: c2

 width: 64 bits

 clock: 33MHz

 capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list

 configuration: latency=0

 resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d057ffff
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to change the brightness? Is there something I am missing? Would it possibly work if I installed an earlier version of ubuntu?

Comment: are you sure it isn't broken somewhere else besides the OS? physical hardware maybe a bios adjustment? If you get the install usb and "try without installing" will it show the same behavior? I don't play on my laptop much, but I remember some kind of "night-light" setting on some distros, does that sound familiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. It turns out I just needed to upgrade the kernel to 5.7.8.